# Data Access Layer design : Different providers same tables and singleton

Tags: c#, database, design-patterns, data-access-layer

I need to build a Data Access Library to be used from many small applications afterwards.

It will heavily use the DataReader objects. The tables may exist with same structure either in SQL Servers or in DB2/400. This means that a method for example

```
GetItemsByWarehouse()
```

Must be able to run either against SQL Server DB or DB2. Where it will run depends on the server availability and user selection.

What i plan to do (and need advice on it) is :

1. Implement the DAL based on Singleton design Pattern to ensure that i will have only one instance of my Library.
2. Have a property that will set the connection string.
3. Have a property that will set if the target server is AS400 or SQL.

I dont know if this course of action is correct. Should i implement point #3 or i could get the type from the connection string?

Also How i should implement such a method as above? check the property and decide inside the method if i will use `Sqlconnection` or `OleDbConnection` e.t.c?

Comment: Better yet, I'd suggest you pick a micro Orm you like and just add the DB2 suport to it. It's less code and you'll develop faster as you would already have an example of how to do it

Comment: I just want to exercise myself on manually using the design patterns and principles. After all the size of the apps do not justify the orm. I want to have a fairly good understanding before i dive into ORM (EF most probably).

Comment: there is a differnce between a micro ORM (which is basically a group of helpers on top of Ado.Net) and an ORM like NHibernate or Ef which are pretty complex with many features aiming to completly abstract RDBMS access. AFAIK EF doesn't support DB2, if you just want an easy way to access db but to still send SQL statements directly to the db go with a micro.  IMO there are very few cases where a real ORM make sense to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I paste this code from my micro Orm . There are multiple overloads for the constructor to specify what Db you want used.

```
 public class DbAccess : IDisposable
{
    public DbAccess()
    {
        var cnx=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0];
        if (cnx==null) throw new InvalidOperationException("I need a connection!!!");

        Init(cnx.ConnectionString,ProviderFactory.GetProviderByName(cnx.ProviderName));
    }

    public DbAccess(string connectionStringName)
    {
        var cnx = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName];
        if (cnx == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("I need a connection!!!");

        Init(cnx.ConnectionString, ProviderFactory.GetProviderByName(cnx.ProviderName));
    }

    public DbAccess(string cnxString,string provider)
    {
        Init(cnxString,ProviderFactory.GetProviderByName(provider));
    }

    public DbAccess(string cnxString,DBType provider)
    {
      Init(cnxString,ProviderFactory.GetProvider(provider));
    }

    public DbAccess(string cnxString,IHaveDbProvider provider)
    {
        Init(cnxString, provider);
    } //other stuff
   }
```

Note that the DAO (DbAccess) doesn't care about the concrete provider. 
Here's how the ProviderFactory looks. Here you can add a method to detect the db and to return a provider.

```
   internal static class ProviderFactory
{
    public static IHaveDbProvider GetProviderByName(string providerName)
    {
        switch (providerName)
        {
            case SqlServerProvider.ProviderName:return new SqlServerProvider();
            case MySqlProvider.ProviderName:return new MySqlProvider();
            case PostgresProvider.ProviderName:return new PostgresProvider();
            case OracleProvider.ProviderName:return new OracleProvider();
            case SqlServerCEProvider.ProviderName:return new SqlServerCEProvider();
            case SqliteProvider.ProviderName:return new SqliteProvider();
        }
        throw new Exception("Unkown provider");
    }

    public static IHaveDbProvider GetProvider(DBType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case DBType.SqlServer: return new SqlServerProvider();
            case DBType.SqlServerCE: return new SqlServerCEProvider();
            case DBType.MySql: return new MySqlProvider();
            case DBType.PostgreSQL:return new PostgresProvider();
            case DBType.Oracle:return new OracleProvider();
            case DBType.SQLite:return new SqliteProvider();
        }
        throw new Exception("Unkown provider");
    }
}
```

For more code snippets and inspiration you can check the [Github repo](https://github.com/sapiens/SqlFu/tree/master/src/SqlFu)

I would advice against the Singleton pattern, it's much better to let a DI container to manage the instance life. Also, the app should use the interface of the DAO not the concrete instance (this will help you in the future).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)

You can have an interface with the DAL contracts and an implementations for each context. Using a Factory it can decide which implementation will use in each case. The factory will need the "switch rule" to decide what to use.

Comment: So you are saying that i will not have one implementation of the method? The trick here is that the queries and the results are the same BUT one time i may be using SQL server and the other AS400. The Abstract factory will have to decide on which method to call. What if i want to have one method for both? Or this is not a good practice?

Comment: No, you will have two implementations for the same method. Your implemantations (SQL and AS400) will fullfil the interface. When the Abstract Factory decides which implementation to use (depending on user preferences or whatever) the calling class (which is using the interface) won't know the implementation. This way you will encapsulate the DAL, and make it interface oriented.

Comment: Ok and i think that combining Abstract Factory with singleton will give me the desired result. But if i didnt have to distinct between 2 underlying data providers and i only wanted to choose between of multiple SQL Servers, i would only need to implement just a property for connection string? and of course still apply the singleton design.